# OS X command line application cannot find directory while called from Java

Tags: java, macos, command-line

If I run this in terminal it works fine:

```
lsof -F n +D /some/directory
```

but when I run the same thing from Java it does not:

```
                    Process lsof = new ProcessBuilder("lsof", "-F", "n", "+D", "'/some/directory'").start();
                    lsof.waitFor();

                    if (lsof.exitValue() != 0) {
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        try {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(lsof.getErrorStream()));
                            String line = null;
                            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line);
                                sb.append("\n");
                            }

                            log.warning("STDOUT:\n" + sb.toString());
                        } finally {
                            if (reader != null) {
                                reader.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

When called from Java it returns:

```
STDOUT:
  lsof: WARNING: can't stat('/some/directory'): No such file or directory
lsof 4.85
 latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
 latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
 latest man page: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
 usage: [-?abhlnNoOPRtUvV] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[cgG]]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--] [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Does `/some/directory` exist? Is it an absolute or relative path?

Comment: it may be that it is reading your path as a relative path. Try assembling your path using one of the [system properties.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Path is absolute. I am using java.nio.file.Path's method toAbsolutePath() to create the path string and it is exactly the same as the one I type in command line (which works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new ProcessBuilder("lsof", "-F", "n", "+D", "'/some/directory'")
                                             ^               ^
```

Remove the single quotes surrounding `/some/directory`. They are being passed through to the `lsof` program and being interpreted as part of the pathname.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out last night myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'm sorry for making a answer instead of a comment. Maybe it's not the issue, but Mac OS usually switches quotes and other marks automatically. This can screw the execution of some commands. I don't think that IDEs use that setting but if you are writing for example in TextEditor - I don't think you are btw - this will happen.

Even if this is not your problem, if you didn't change this already, I suggest you should do it to avoid future problems with this issue.

To change this:
Preferences > keyboard

Hope this helps someone.